# Can't Implement images from source

Tags: javascript, image-size

I am creating a web portfolio and I am using different photos/images for a responsive web page. But I am receiving the same error and I can not find the solution
.The reason I am using two different sets of images is that I am having vanilla javascript code for carousels but I am open to a different solution.

I named images so they could be added thru the for loop for example the first image is called img1.jpg, the second is named img2.jpg, etc.

```
function changeSource() {
    const Images = document.querySelectorAll('.slides img');
    for (let i = 1; i < Images.length; i++) {
        Images[i].src = "../Assets/square/img" + i + ".jpg"; 
    }
}
```

error message: 1 GET localhost:82/Assets/square/img6.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Here is the HTML markup

```
        <images>
            <section class="slides">
                <img src="Assets/home/img4.jpg" id="lastclone">
                <img src="Assets/home/img1.jpg">
                <img src="Assets/home/img2.jpg">
                <img src="Assets/home/img3.jpg">
                <img src="Assets/home/img4.jpg">
                <img src="Assets/home/img5.jpg">
                <img src="Assets/home/img1.jpg" id="firstclone">
                <img src="Assets/home/img2.jpg">
            </section>
        </images>
    <script src="js/load.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/resize.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you navigate to `localhost:82/Assets` can you see the folder of images? The message indicates the resource cannot be found

Comment: If you mean by that in the chrome no, but still I don't really know how to have them loaded before the page opening. Thanks for the response, I kinda missed that piece of information and I am hoping that this sentence is going to help

Comment: I don't think your issue lies within your code. If you went to `localhost:82/Assets/square/img6.jpg` you'll probably see that doesn't exist. Is this with express? If so, you need to set a public folder, and add them into their. If it's not express, would you mind sharing how you have setup the local server to run, or is it just html?

Comment: it is a basic HTML markup but I'll share

Comment: @TomRoman the first set of images loaded normally but the rest is calling to have an error

Comment: If they're giving a 404 error, it means that it's literally not found and doesn't exist. If you also got a 404 going to `localhost:82/Assets/home` then they're not on the server. What are you using to run/create the server environment to allow access to port 82?

Comment: @TomRoman I am using a XAMPP

Comment: @TomRoman but I am still using the existing directory and I am confused